# Apache Error: Failed to load URL https://localhost/ with error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (-102)

Tags: apache, fortigate, forticlient

I am trying to install Forticlient EMS onto Windows server. The apache service has been running fine however when running the application it loads with the following error:

Failed to load URL https://localhost/ with error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (-102).

There is not much online to work with regarding this error. I changed the ports in the .conf file to 82 instead of 80 as it was clashing but stuck as to why this error is being produced. Has anyone come across this? This is not running in Chrome rather i am launching Forticlient EMS application for this error to show on the application.